# Sort 2 arrays in C by a joint logic

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Given two arrays

```
a = [1,3,2,8,5,6]
b = [4,3,2,5,1,2]
```

I would like to sort them in "one pass" where the "logic" involves the two arrays, meaning:
if

```
int sortBySum(index i, index j){
    if (a[i]+b[i] > a[j]+b[j]){
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The output of the two arrays will be

```
a = [2,1,3,5,6,8]
b = [2,4,3,1,2,5]
```

Because the original `arrays sum` is `a+b=[5,6,4,13,6,8]`

Comment: @TanveerBadar Not agreeing here with usage of  the phrase "any code". I think we should be polite to the OP while clarifying.

Comment: OP, please add the code where you are calling `sortBySum()` and how you are handling those return values `1` and `-1` ?

Comment: @DsCpp A simplest way is to write your own sorting function that uses for example the method bubble sort. In this case there is no need to create an additional array.

Comment: Use any sorting algorithm and adapt it to your use of two arrays and your comparison function. You could use the `qsort` library function if it is sufficient to sort an index array instead of sorting your two data arrays or if you replace your two arrays with an array of structures `struct { int a; int b } array[] = { {1, 4}, {3, 3}, {2, 2}, ... };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a task is about sorting, `qsort` is - in most cases - your friend.

But `qsort` can only sort one array. So you need to copy the elements from array `a` and `b` into an array of structs containing the data from `a` and `b`. Then use `qsort` and then copy the data back.

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  int a;
  int b;
} common_data;

// Compare function for qsort
int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
  common_data* pa = (common_data*)p1;
  common_data* pb = (common_data*)p2;
  return ((pa->a + pa->b) - (pb->a + pb->b));
}

int main(void)
{
  int a[] = {1,3,2,8,5,6};
  int b[] = {4,3,2,5,1,2};
  size_t sz = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
  common_data carr[sz];

  // Copy to common array
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
  {
    carr[i].a = a[i];
    carr[i].b = b[i];
  }

  // Sort common array
  qsort(carr, sz, sizeof(carr[0]), cmp);

  // Copy to back to original array
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
  {
    a[i] = carr[i].a;
    b[i] = carr[i].b;
  }

  // Print array a
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
  {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  // Print array b
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
  {
    printf("%d ", b[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 1 3 5 6 8
2 4 3 1 2 5
```

Comment: This is the correct way. One nitpick however, is that `((pa->a + pa->b) - (pb->a + pb->b))` could potentially underflow.

Answer (score 1):

A primitive approach can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 6 };
    int b[] = { 4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2 };

    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    printf( "a: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "b: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", b[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t n = N, last; !( n < 2 ); n = last )
    {
        for ( size_t i = last = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( a[i] + b[i] < a[i-1] + b[i-1] )
            {
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i]    = a[i-1];
                a[i-1]  = tmp;

                tmp     = b[i];
                b[i]    = b[i-1];
                b[i-1]  = tmp;

                last = i;
            }
        }
    }

    printf( "a: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "b: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", b[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a: 1 3 2 8 5 6 
b: 4 3 2 5 1 2 

a: 2 1 3 5 6 8 
b: 2 4 3 1 2 5
```

The code that sorts the arrays using the method bubble sort can be moved in a separate function.